# How do I start php7.0-fpm with supervisord?

Tags: php-fpm, docker, fastcgi, supervisord, php7

I am trying to build a dockerized ubuntu 16.04lts with apache2 and nginx with php7.0-fpm

Commands I have used but did not work

```
[program:php-fpm7.0]
command = /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 --daemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

and

```
[program:php-fpm7.0]
command = /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 -c /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

and

```
[program:php-fpm7.0]
command = /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 -c /etc/php/7.0/fpm
autostart=true
autorestart=true
priority=5
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Below are the error logs from docker when I try to run as containers

from the apache2 container

```
2016-06-26 20:04:21,488 CRIT Set uid to user 0
2016-06-26 20:04:21,496 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-06-26 20:04:21,496 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-06-26 20:04:21,496 INFO supervisord started with pid 8
2016-06-26 20:04:22,499 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm7.0' with pid 11
2016-06-26 20:04:22,500 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 12
2016-06-26 20:04:22,571 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
[26-Jun-2016 20:04:22] ERROR: Unable to create the PID file (/run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid).: No such file or directory (2)
[26-Jun-2016 20:04:22] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
2016-06-26 20:04:22,609 INFO exited: php-fpm7.0 (exit status 78; not expected)
2016-06-26 20:04:23,611 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm7.0' with pid 74
2016-06-26 20:04:23,613 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 75
httpd (pid 16) already running
2016-06-26 20:04:23,669 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
[26-Jun-2016 20:04:23] ERROR: Unable to create the PID file (/run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid).: No such file or directory (2)
[26-Jun-2016 20:04:23] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
2016-06-26 20:04:23,694 INFO exited: php-fpm7.0 (exit status 78; not expected)
2016-06-26 20:04:25,698 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm7.0' with pid 79
2016-06-26 20:04:25,700 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 80
httpd (pid 16) already running
2016-06-26 20:04:25,758 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
[26-Jun-2016 20:04:25] ERROR: Unable to create the PID file (/run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid).: No such file or directory (2)
[26-Jun-2016 20:04:25] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
2016-06-26 20:04:25,784 INFO exited: php-fpm7.0 (exit status 78; not expected)
2016-06-26 20:04:28,788 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm7.0' with pid 84
2016-06-26 20:04:28,789 INFO spawned: 'apache2' with pid 85
httpd (pid 16) already running
2016-06-26 20:04:28,847 INFO exited: apache2 (exit status 0; not expected)
2016-06-26 20:04:28,857 INFO gave up: apache2 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
[26-Jun-2016 20:04:28] ERROR: Unable to create the PID file (/run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid).: No such file or directory (2)
[26-Jun-2016 20:04:28] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
2016-06-26 20:04:28,872 INFO exited: php-fpm7.0 (exit status 78; not expected)
2016-06-26 20:04:29,873 INFO gave up: php-fpm7.0 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

and

from the nginx container

```
2016-06-26 11:19:02,307 CRIT Set uid to user 0
2016-06-26 11:19:02,320 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2016-06-26 11:19:02,320 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2016-06-26 11:19:02,321 INFO supervisord started with pid 14
2016-06-26 11:19:03,323 INFO spawned: 'php7.0-fpm' with pid 17
2016-06-26 11:19:03,324 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 18
[26-Jun-2016 11:19:03] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock': No such file or directory (2)
[26-Jun-2016 11:19:03] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
2016-06-26 11:19:03,406 INFO exited: php7.0-fpm (exit status 78; not expected)
2016-06-26 11:19:04,409 INFO spawned: 'php7.0-fpm' with pid 20
2016-06-26 11:19:04,409 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
[26-Jun-2016 11:19:04] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock': No such file or directory (2)
[26-Jun-2016 11:19:04] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
2016-06-26 11:19:04,465 INFO exited: php7.0-fpm (exit status 78; not expected)
2016-06-26 11:19:06,470 INFO spawned: 'php7.0-fpm' with pid 21
[26-Jun-2016 11:19:06] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock': No such file or directory (2)
[26-Jun-2016 11:19:06] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
2016-06-26 11:19:06,527 INFO exited: php7.0-fpm (exit status 78; not expected)
2016-06-26 11:19:09,532 INFO spawned: 'php7.0-fpm' with pid 30
[26-Jun-2016 11:19:09] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock': No such file or directory (2)
[26-Jun-2016 11:19:09] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
2016-06-26 11:19:09,592 INFO exited: php7.0-fpm (exit status 78; not expected)
2016-06-26 11:19:10,594 INFO gave up: php7.0-fpm entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2016/06/26 11:19:13 [info] 19#19: *1 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.99.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

So my question is how do I correctly use `supervisord` to start php7.0-fpm/php-fpm7.0 in the docker containers.

Also understand that when I login into these containers and run this command then it starts to work! What am I doing wrong

```
service php7.0-fpm start
```

When I run the above command after fpm fails to start when container is ran, then it works. How do I do this with supervisord so I don't need to manually start with init.d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see there is no /run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid file.
This file is created when php7.0-fpm starts.
So I solved this issue by adding to Dockerfile:

```
RUN service php7.0-fpm start
```

Of course after php-fpm installation :)

Comment: i thought that was the job of supervisord? so i have to do that to replace supervisord or use both?

Comment: Just first time - during build. Then /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid will be created and stored inside build image, so supervisord can start and manage your services.
I'm not sure but probably you can create this file manually or at least /var/run/php directory with proper permissions.

Comment: i just noticed that supervisord does not restart php anymore after running the start command in dockerfile...i made changes to php ini file and supervisord is unable to restart php check this http://serverfault.com/questions/837835/how-do-i-restart-php7-fpm-with-supervisord

Answer (score 18):

Creating the `/var/run/php` in the build i.e. `mkdir -p /var/run/php`and then starting php-fpm in supervisord

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:php-fpm]
command=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 -F
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
stdout_logfile=/var/log/php-fpm/stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/var/log/php-fpm/stderr.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
exitcodes=0
```

Also works.

If you copy paste the above make sure to also `mkdir -p /var/log/php-fpm`
for supervisord to write log files to.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: better answer than limestreet.  Comment: avoid manually creating /var/run/php by changing the pid/sock-path in /etc/php7/php-fpm.conf to /run/php.{sock,pid} . mostly we'll use a custom conf anyways

Comment: worked tanx alot

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the following error when starting php-fpm7.4 in Docker with supervisor:

**ERROR: Another FPM instance seems to already listen on /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock**

What fixed it was adding the -F to the end of the command, which by the help indicates put the process into foreground:

```
-F, --nodaemonize force to stay in foreground, and ignore daemonize option from config file
```

Here is my supervisor.conf:

```
[program:php-fpm]
  command=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.4 -F
  stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
  stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
  stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
  stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```