# how do i restart php7-fpm with supervisord?

Tags: php-fpm, docker, supervisord, php7

I have a custom docker image for apache and php7-fpm but whenever i make changes to the php ini file and use supervisord to retsart php7-fpm after those changes during image building before running the container from the image i noticed i have been unable to make php7-fpm restart. So the changes i make to the php ini file never gets reflected

But when i log into the running container and try to retsart php7-fpm then i see those changes

Here is what my supervisord config has

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:php-fpm7.0]
command = /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 -c /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf
autorestart=true

[program:apache2]
command=/bin/bash -c "source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND"
autorestart=true
```

Here is my start.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
#echo "export HOSTNAME=$(hostname)" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
sed -i -e "s/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -i -e "s/;short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -i -e "s/;display_errors = Off/display_errors = On/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -ri 's/^upload_max_filesize\s*=\s*.+/upload_max_filesize = 450M/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -ri 's/^max_input_time\s*=\s*.+/max_input_time = 300/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -ri 's/^memory_limit\s*=\s*.+/memory_limit = 640M/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -ri 's/^post_max_size\s*=\s*.+/post_max_size = 450M/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -ri 's/^max_execution_time\s*=\s*.+/max_execution_time = 300/g' /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
sed -i -e "s/;daemonize\s*=\s*yes/daemonize = no/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf
sed -i -e "s/;catch_workers_output\s*=\s*yes/catch_workers_output = yes/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
sed -i -e "s/pm.max_children = 5/pm.max_children = 9/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
sed -i -e "s/pm.start_servers = 2/pm.start_servers = 3/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
sed -i -e "s/pm.min_spare_servers = 1/pm.min_spare_servers = 2/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
sed -i -e "s/pm.max_spare_servers = 3/pm.max_spare_servers = 4/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
sed -i -e "s/pm.max_requests = 500/pm.max_requests = 200/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
sed -i -e "s/;clear_env = no/clear_env = no/g" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Please help with how to **restart** php7-fpm when changes are made to the php ini file with a `start.sh` script while creating the docker image

P.S.

You may be wondering why do i need to restart php7-fpm if it only needs to be started, well no way to get php7-fpm to work with docker except i actually start it first in my docker file like below. Whenever i remove that line from my dockerfile, it does not work. If anyone has apache 2.4 and php7-fpm setup in docker that works without that way PLEASE send me the link to their image!

```
RUN service php7.0-fpm start
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just added this line to the `start.sh` script

`service php7.0-fpm restart`

and just like that all issues got resolved!

Didn't realize it was as easy as just adding a bash command to the start.sh script